Perform user-defined function on grouped pd.Series of a pd.DataFrame
I am trying to apply functions to two/multiple pd.Series in a grouped pd.DataFrame and cannot wrap my head around how to do it.
Suppose we have a pd.DataFrame with the following layout:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'group_var':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                             'col1':[1,2,1,1,2,1,3,1,3,1,1,2],
                             'col2':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,3,1,3]})

Now, I want to apply some user-defined function that makes some computation using col1 and col2:
def f(col1, col2):
    new_col = pd.Series([val + sum(col1) for val in col2])
    return new_col

The result I am aiming for looks something like this (a grouped application of f on df for each group in group_var for inputs col1 and col2):
 0     6
 1     7
 2     6
 3     7
 4     8
 5     9
 6     8
 7    10
 8     8
 9    10
10     8
11    10
dtype: int64

I tried using apply, but only came out to computations row-by-row. How can I apply function f to the whole grouped column/pd.Series with respect to group_var?

IIUC, you can do it like this:
def f(x):
    new_col = pd.Series([val + x['col1'].sum() for val in x['col2']], index=x.index)
    return new_col

df.groupby('group_var', group_keys=False, as_index=False)[['col1', 'col2']].apply(f)

Output:
0      6
1      7
2      6
3      7
4      8
5      9
6      8
7     10
8      8
9     10
10     8
11    10
dtype: int64


This gives me a TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type. Omitting the index  parameter lets me compute the result without problems, but the form is similar to m-sarabi's answer before the stack() operation.

What version of pandas are you using?

Currently pandas 1.5.3. Seems like I am pretty outdated on that part. I suppose you suggest updating? I will look into what updating to a newer version does.

Yes.  Pandas 2.2.2 is out now.  However, if this part of a bigger software product watch your dependencies.

Just updated and everything works fine now and also independent from whether the row counts per group are identical for the whole frame or not. Thank you very much for the great solution.

You can use groupby('group_var') and then apply the function f to each group.
Then convert it to a flat series by using stack and reset_index(drop=True):
result = df.groupby('group_var')[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda g: pd.Series(f(g['col1'], g['col2'])))

result = result.stack().reset_index(drop=True)

Update:
To handle different group sizes, use index=g.index in the apply method` to retain the group index, and then simply drop the indexes.
Example with different group sizes:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'group_var': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'col1': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1],
    'col2': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2]})


def f(col1, col2):
    return [val + sum(col1) for val in col2]


result = df.groupby('group_var')[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda g: pd.Series(f(g['col1'], g['col2']), index=g.index))
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)
print(result)

Output:
0      6
1      7
2      6
3      7
4     10
5     11
6     10
7     12
8     10
9     11
10    13
11    11
12    13
13    11
14    12
dtype: int64


This works as long as the number of items per group is identical. If one group has a different item count, I get a TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type. Do you have an idea how different group sizes could be handled?

@ReelSaemon As others suggested, you should consider updating pandas. I updated the answer to support different group sizes.

Thank you very much for this. It works completely fine and as expected now after updating pandas, also for different group sizes. I like the way the function can be in its original form due to the use of lambda and wrapping its result in the indexed pd.Series. However, I already accepted Scott's answer, I hope you understand.

It is fine, I'm glad it helps. Have a good time
